# Prevent border clipping my image

Tags: css

Okay so I have an image and I want a border outline around it (which I can get). But even if the border is 'x' far away from my image, the image still gets clipped. *ONLY HAPPENS WHEN BORDER-RADIUS PROPERTY IS SET*. Hopefully, that made some sense but here's some images to show what I mean. Btw sorry if this is anywhere else it's hard to think of good keywords when there's a border-image-outset property and other crap.

```css
   .slideshow {
   display: none;
   margin-top: -50px;
   font-size: 25px;
   }

.slideshow table {
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow table tr td {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon_circle {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td span {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 90px;
  padding: 30px;
  border: #000 5px solid;
}
```

```html
  <div class="slideshow">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><img class="icon_circle" width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
        <td><img class="icon_circle" width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
        <td><img class="icon_circle" width="90px"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Lorem ipdrepnt occaecqui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
```

Images:

**No-Clipping**

[image]

**Clipping**

[image]

[Winrar logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png)

Comment: Show us your code, consider reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try reducing the border-radius

Comment: I have, the image is 90px so if I go less it become warped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
overflow:none;
```

on the div that's holding your image.

Comment: there is no div, the image has a class with a border and border radius and overflow: hidden and 30px padding

Comment: well if you add border-radius in the image itself then it'll be clipped. Try adding a div that will contain the image and use border-radius on the div instead of image.

Comment: That solved it pretty easy without messing around much! Put the images in a div and added " display: table; margin: 0 auto; display: block; " and now it works. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Add padding in the image e.g.

```
.image {
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It has padding.. That's why the actual border is displaced from the image

Comment: You should add more padding so if 30pixels still results to the image being clipped then change it to 40px or 50px etc.

Comment: Maybe your css is cached and you don't see the edit you made in the css. I'm trying it in my local devel and it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you just remove the overflow:hidden: it should not clip, and you should change the html to have the class on the wrapping  element

```css
.icon_circle {
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    border: #000 5px solid;
}
```

```html
  <div class="slideshow">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="icon_circle" ><img width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
        <td class="icon_circle"><img  width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
        <td class="icon_circle"><img width="90px"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Lorem ipdrepnt occaecqui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: That's what I had at first, neither work.. It does for your circular images though because the pixel offset from each corner I assume.

Answer (score 1):

Give those css properties to td tag, instead of `<img>`

For example
https://jsfiddle.net/kqogcLk4/

Comment: Thank you Giulo, this worked pretty well but my table is full width and now I dunno what to do ahaha but I should be able to figure it out from here. Cheers =D

Comment: Glad I helped you :) Have a nice day :)

Comment: Reckon you could help again? It's for my yr 11 task. I just updated the css so people could see what's influencing the table cause I'm still stuck, but u solved the clipping so ty :)

Comment: We all would be willing to help you out. Just create another thread about the new situation, as this problem is resolved already, and also for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your are giving `padding` and `border-radius` to the `image` itself. Instead, add a `SPAN` tag give it `border` properties and inset `img` tag inside it. It will give you the desired output.

```css
.icon_circle {
  overflow: hidden;
}

span {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  border: #000 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><span>
        <img class="icon_circle" width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt="">
        </span></td>
      <td><span><img class="icon_circle" width="90px" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></span></td>
      <td><span><img class="icon_circle" width="90px"  src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></span></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>Lorem ipdrepnt occaecqui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the images inside a div and giving the divs the 'icon_circle' class fixed it. Had to add a few extra properties. Here's the working code for anyone who encounters same problem. =D

```css
    #boxes .box img{
  height: 90px;
}
  .slideshow {
  display: none;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.slideshow table {
  width: 100%;
}

.slideshow table tr td {
  text-align: center;
}

.icon_circle {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  padding: 25px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  border: #000 5px solid;
}
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></div></td>
        <td><div class="icon_circle" ><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2SF1.png" alt=""></div></td> 

      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>Lorem ipdrepnt occaecqui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
```